# Java_Hibernate 3_CLOB_ORA-01461

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, clob

I added a new CLOB Column in a table and modified my hbm.xml - file to use this new column (the old column was varchar2 and therefore too small):

(I used random-names for demonstration purposes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="test.com.TestDO" table="TESTTABLE">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">SEQ_SEQUENCENAME</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
     </property>
        <property name="columnName1" type="java.util.Date">
          <column name="COLUMN_NAME1"/>
        </property>
         <property name="columnName2" type="java.lang.String">
          <column name="COLUMN_NAME2"/>
        </property>
        <property name="columnName3" type="java.lang.String">
          <column name="COLUMN_CLOB"/>
        </property>
      </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

As you can see, my clob-column (COLUMN_CLOB) is defined as last, because first I got this exception:

```
ORA-24816: Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column
```

I searched for this error and the solution was to place the clob binding at the last in the insert-statement, so I defined the clob-column in the hbm.xml file to be last, as you can see above.

Now I am not getting the ORA-24816 exception, but I am getting this exception:

```
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

The generated Insert-Statement looks like this:

```
insert into TESTTABLE(COLUMN_NAME1, COLUMN_NAME2, COLUMN_CLOB, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)];
```

As you may have noticed, the COLUMN_CLOB - column does not appear last in the generated Insert-Statement. I don't know if the order in the hbm-xml -file affects the order of the columns in the generated insert-statement?

But anyway, I am not getting the ORA-24816 anymore just ORA-01461. I don't know how to solve this issue.

I am using Hibernate 3 and Oracle Version: Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

EDIT:

I have the exact same issue as described here:
http://newtechnobuzzz.blogspot.ch/2014/07/ora-24816-expanded-non-long-bind-data.html#.Wcy-QdFpHRY

I have tried the following solutions:

- Chaning the order of getter and setter methods does not work
- Changing the order of the declared property in the hbm.xml -file does
  not work

The problem described on the link and on other sites, state that this excpetion
occurs if you try to insert data in both the varchar2 and the clob columns (2 strings with a length of 4000). However I am only inserting data into the clob-column which is bigger then 4000. I am not using the old varchar2 - column anymore.

Now, I am trying to solve this by using this solution:
It can solved by writing two update queries. Firstly, save/update the entity by an Update query and then write another query to update LOB columns in that entity.

However, I dont quite understand, how I should modify my code. My method looks like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
public TestDO saveTest(TestDO test) {

    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(test);

    return test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the property type has not been declared correctly for the CLOB column, try that:

```
<property name="columnName3" length="100000" type="StringClob">
     <column name="COLUMN_CLOB"/>
</property>
```

Comment: But I am saving a string. The string is larger than 4000, that's why I want to save them in a clob-column. Therefore I need to use java.lang String as type right? I have also other tables which have clob-columns and are with declared as java.lang.String in hbm.xml-file and it works

Comment: my guess is there is mismatch between the column type and the datatype passed to the column, maybe you should use java.sql.Clob instead of java.lang.String
If it works for other tables then maybe it's something with the columns order between the insert staement and the column declaration

Comment: But In java I am passing a String, so I cannot use java.sql.Clob but java.lang.String because my property in Java is a string. I am trying to add sql-type="CLOB"  and test it

Comment: I have tried your and also other solutions, but it is not working..do you know how to change the insertion order of the values, because I also think that i may be something with the columns order between the insert staement and the column declaration

Comment: insert into TESTTABLE(ID,COLUMN_NAME1, COLUMN_NAME2, COLUMN_CLOB) values (?, ?, ?, ?)];
are you sure the values passed corresponds to the right columns, maybe it takes values in the order they are defined your xml

Comment: I think i found the issue, i may have this problem described here:
http://www.odi.ch/weblog/posting.php?posting=496, however after I changed the order in the hbm.xml - file , my clob column appears after all varchar2 columns, but the id-column is last, cannot change that..i dont know how to solve this